# Valid CSS, XHTML logo generator

Tags: css, xhtml, icons

I once knew a website where the user could generate the little W3C valid CSS tags which looked much nicer than the too large W3C official ones.
It was also possible to fill the icons with whatever content and color for other stuff.

I've lost the bookmark and wasn't able to google it, can you post it and maybe other such resources?

EDIT: and yes I know ...

Can I modify the existing icons to create my own?

No. The validator's icons are distributed under the W3C document license, which allows distribution but does not allow derivative works.

BUT I don't care, cause I don't want my design to look ugly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably mean [antipixel's icons](http://antipixel.com/blog/archives/2002/10/22/steal_these_buttons.html) and [LucaZappa's Brilliant Button Maker](http://www.lucazappa.com/brilliantMaker/buttonImage.php).

[Picture of the icons http://img353.imageshack.us/img353/1368/stealthesebuttonsli4.gif](http://img353.imageshack.us/img353/1368/stealthesebuttonsli4.gif)

From the [antipixel website](http://antipixel.com):

> **If you want them, they’re yours**,
>   **gratis, no strings attached.**
>
> **Pull them straight off the main page**
>   **here if you want, and if you’d like to**
>   **change anything about them, go ahead**
>   **and do that.** I’m posting the Photoshop
>   files below so you can download those
>   and change anything you want. You do
>   not need to give me credit or provide
>   a link back here or anything like
>   that. (Some people are already using
>   them and at least one kind soul has
>   posted such a link back here. You
>   don’t need to do that anymore, but
>   thank you for being a more than decent
>   person.)

[RSS buttons are also available.](http://www.antipixel.com/blog/archives/2002/10/23/rss_buttons.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's antipixel's orginal badges:

http://www.antipixel.com/blog/archives/2002/10/22/steal_these_buttons.html

http://www.antipixel.com/blog/archives/2002/10/23/rss_buttons.html

And this is the generator:

http://www.lucazappa.com/brilliantMaker/buttonImage.php

Answer (score 1):

Be careful though, W3C is strict about their logo usage (as is any company):
[W3C Logo and Icon Usage](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/logo-usage-20000308)

Comment: well yes and no... I mean, as long as it's a different image, there is no problem:

Q2: Can I use an image in a link to the W3C Web site (e.g., to the W3C validator) that is not derived from the W3C logo?

Yes, you may link to the W3C site with images that are not derived from the W3C logo.

Comment: True, but some of the smaller badges use the W3C logo. Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be a preacher of some kind, I'm just giving the other side of the story :P

Comment: sure, I think I would agree to avoid the little W3C logo in them and just write valid css

Answer (score 1):

You don't want your design to look amateurish? Then don't put those logos on. The only people likely to care whether your site is valid are going to check whether they see the logo or not.

Comment: maybe true but a) I'm for standards and their promotion and b) and more importantly it's the wish of the customer in this case

Comment: I think I understand the reasons of my customer, it can make your site look more trustworthy to ppl.